# Remove "." (dot) after each word enclosed in pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to remove "." (dot) after each word enclosed in a pattern.

**Input** :

```
Lorem *|Ipsum.|* is simply *|dummy.|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry.|*.
```

**Output** :

```
Lorem *|Ipsum|* is simply *|dummy|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry|*.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture a text of `*|sometext.|*` pattern using this regex, with appropriate grouping,

```
(\*\|[^|]+)\.(\|\*)
```

and replace with `$1$2` where `*|sometext` part is captured in group1 and `.` is excluded from grouping so it gets removed and `|*` part is grouped in group2.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewcLdB/2/)**

**[Python code demo](https://rextester.com/DHUG30461)**

```
$s = "Lorem *|Ipsum.|* is simply *|dummy.|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry.|*.";
echo preg_replace('/(\*\|[^|]+)\.(\|\*)/', '$1$2', $s);
```

Prints following with dot removed inside `*|text.|*`,

```
Lorem *|Ipsum|* is simply *|dummy|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry|*.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to do so:

```
$string = 'Lorem *|Ipsum.|* is simply *|dummy.|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry.|*.';

$output = preg_replace('/(\.\|)/s', '|', $string);

var_dump($output);
```

#### Output:

```
"Lorem *|Ipsum|* is simply *|dummy|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry|*."
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use **str_replace()** for that.

```
$string = 'Lorem *|Ipsum.|* is simply *|dummy.|* text of the *|printing|* and typesetting *|industry.|*.';
$replacedString = str_replace('.|', '|', $string);`
```

You can check more about the function in here https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_str_replace